# Filter "User Information List" to get active user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Can I get list of user using "User Information List" hidden list with following criteria:

1. Only Active Users
2. Excluded SharePoint Groups

```
http://siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items?
```

Currently if you query this list it will give all users exist in list.

Why I am planning to use this, because ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser is not returning user id in response and for getting user id you have to query again. So I basically I want to avoid two call using REST.

Any idea?

Comment: This hidden list also contains the users who have left the company so they may contain users who are not active

Comment: SharePoint has no concept of "active" users. It is best to use Azure AD sign-in logs to determine what active accounts there are in the environment. Microsoft is introducing a feature to automate this process - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/review-and-remove-aad-inactive-users-in-public-preview/ba-p/3290632

Comment: That aad thing is out of my scope, hence I can not wait for it implementation. I am looking for a way to query users in SharePoint with less huddle